# Ion Slide Overflow

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ion-slides

I am using ion-slide and transforming my image on second slide zooming IN and OUT and it overflows on my main slide.

Here's my main slide and the second slide is overflowing:

[image]

HTML:

```
<ion-content>
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide class="slide-main">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row class="row-main">
        <img class="img-main" src="https://cdopromos.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/maxs-restaurant-chicken-all-you-can.jpg">
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide class="slide-secondaruy">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row class="row-secondary">
        <img class="img-secondary" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/iP2XG4WiD4Q2U18hRlCG9375ujydwARovLR8R6HrMLVp3iyH5pteC7RHOivfo3_njckHJyN21we1qmrbc7F3Bc2ao7UyCsMeMh6AGdt4v8loHSu51bHtOEC69e7HedDHrX3A9HRnKDg">
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

CSS:

```
.row-main{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

*{
  padding: 0;
}
.img-secondary{
  height: 100vh;
  transform: scale(1);
    animation: zoominout 30s infinite ;

}

.img-main{

}
.row-secondary{
  z-index: -1;
}
.swiper-slide{
  z-index: -1;

}

@keyframes zoominout {
  0% {
      transform: scale(1,1);
  }
  50% {
      transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
  }
  100% {
      transform: scale(1,1);
  }
}

.slide-main{
  z-index: 99;
}
```

I used z-index and overflow-x:hidden but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if using the `<ion-grid>` is necessary, but if you structure your template code like this it let's the default layout in `<ion-slide>` structure your content.

`html`

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-slides>
    <ion-slide class="slide-main">
      <img class="img-main" src="https://cdopromos.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/maxs-restaurant-chicken-all-you-can.jpg">
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide class="slide-secondary">
      <img class="img-secondary" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2397361/pexels-photo-2397361.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500">
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

In your `scss` of the component go ahead and tell the `<ion-slide>` to hide anything outside of its containing boundary.

```
/**
Add this to your scss
 */
ion-slide {
  overflow-x: hidden!important; // or overflow: hidden or overflow-y: hidden
}
/**
Add this to your scss
 */

.row-main{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

*{
  padding: 0;
}
.img-secondary{
  height: 100vh;
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: zoominout 30s infinite ;

}

.img-main{

}
.row-secondary{
  z-index: -1;
}
.swiper-slide{
  z-index: -1;

}

@keyframes zoominout {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1,1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1,1);
  }
}

.slide-main{
  z-index: 99;
}
```

The end result looks like [this](https://gfycat.com/tanthiscrocodile).